# Iterate over object inside object with javascript that have regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, object

I'm creating some descriptions with `Regex` using the name of the privileges I have, that are these:

```
var privileges = [
    "APP_SOMEONE_SRV",
    "APP_ANYONE_SRV",
    "ADM_AD_XX"
];

var descriptions = {
    "NETWORK": {
        "GROUP": {
            "^APP_(.*)$": {
                "^APP_" : "PATH",
                "^APP_A05_(.*)" : "$1",
                "_SRV" : "ON SERVER"
            },
            "^A05_(.*)" : "Group $1 at AD",
            "^ADM_AD_(.*)": "Administrator $1 at AD",       
        }
    }
}
```

I'm debugging the code with `Chrome's Developer Tool`, printing some vars with `window.console.log`:

```
privileges.forEach(function(role) {
    var base = "NETWORK";
    var type = "GROUP";
    Object.keys(descriptions).forEach(function(baseReg) {
        if (base.match(new RegExp(baseReg))) {
            Object.keys(descriptions[baseReg]).forEach(function(typeReg) {
                if (type.match(new RegExp(typeReg))) {
                    Object.keys(descriptions[baseReg][typeReg]).forEach(function(roleReg) {

                    var reg = RegExp(roleReg);
                    window.console.log("role: " + role);
                    window.console.log("roleReg: " + typeof roleReg + " >> " + roleReg);
                    if (role.match(reg)) {
                        var suggestDescription = role.replace(reg, descriptions[baseReg][typeReg][roleReg]);
                        window.console.log("description: " + suggestDescription);    
                    }
                    if (roleReg == Object.prototype.toString.call(roleReg) === '[object Object]'){
                        window.console.log(roleReg + " is object");
                    }
                    window.console.log("");


                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

On console, I get that "^APP_(.*)$" is always a string, when it should be an object:

```
VM107:31 role: APP_SOMEONE_SRV
VM107:32 roleReg: string >> ^APP_(.*)$
VM107:35 description: [object Object]
VM107:40 
VM107:31 role: APP_SOMEONE_SRV
VM107:32 roleReg: string >> ^A05_(.*)
VM107:40 
VM107:31 role: APP_SOMEONE_SRV
VM107:32 roleReg: string >> ^ADM_AD_(.*)
VM107:40 
VM107:31 role: APP_ANYONE_SRV
VM107:32 roleReg: string >> ^APP_(.*)$
VM107:35 description: [object Object]
VM107:40 
VM107:31 role: APP_ANYONE_SRV
VM107:32 roleReg: string >> ^A05_(.*)
VM107:40 
VM107:31 role: APP_ANYONE_SRV
VM107:32 roleReg: string >> ^ADM_AD_(.*)
VM107:40 
VM107:31 role: ADM_AD_XX
VM107:32 roleReg: string >> ^APP_(.*)$
VM107:40 
VM107:31 role: ADM_AD_XX
VM107:32 roleReg: string >> ^A05_(.*)
VM107:40 
VM107:31 role: ADM_AD_XX
VM107:32 roleReg: string >> ^ADM_AD_(.*)
VM107:35 description: Administrator XX at AD
```

I already tried to change the comparison to check that if the actual roleReg is a object, but it didn't change anything. Does it have other way to iterate over the descriptions, checking before that if the actual one is a object? Because, for example, "^A05_(.*)" is not a object

Comment: Why would you expect it to be an object? In your code, `roleReg` is one of the **keys** of the object; it's not one of the regular expressions your code creates. The variable `reg` contains the RegExp instance, not `roleReg`.

Comment: @Pointy i saw here > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects that it probably be an object, at myHonda var

Comment: "myHonda"?? What? Object property keys are always strings. (Well, they can be Symbol instances in ES2015 but that's not relevant here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roleReg` is the property value (string), which is why. `reg` is the object you are making with that value, and that is an object. ;)

To clarify `Object.keys(descriptions[baseReg][typeReg])` is iterating over `descriptions['NETWORK']['GROUP']` and that will give you the property NAMEs (strings), not the value of the property.  `var reg = RegExp(roleReg);` creates a regex with the property NAME, which is `^APP_(.*)$`.

`descriptions[baseReg][typeReg][roleReg]` will give the you property object you are looking for.

Try this:

```
privileges.forEach(function(role) {
    var base = "NETWORK";
    var type = "GROUP";
    Object.keys(descriptions).forEach(function(baseReg) {
        if (base.match(new RegExp(baseReg))) {
            Object.keys(descriptions[baseReg]).forEach(function(typeReg) {
                if (type.match(new RegExp(typeReg))) {
                    Object.keys(descriptions[baseReg][typeReg]).forEach(function(roleReg) {
                    var reg = RegExp(roleReg);
                    var roleRegValue = descriptions[baseReg][typeReg][roleReg];
                    window.console.log("role: " + role);
                    window.console.log("roleReg Property: " + typeof roleReg + " >> " + roleReg);
                    window.console.log("roleReg Value: " + typeof roleRegValue + " >> " + roleRegValue);
                    if (role.match(reg)) {
                        var suggestDescription = role.replace(reg, descriptions[baseReg][typeReg][roleReg]);
                        window.console.log("description: " + suggestDescription);    
                    }
                    if (roleRegValue == Object.prototype.toString.call(roleRegValue) === '[object Object]'){
                        window.console.log(roleRegValue + " is object");
                    }
                    window.console.log("");


                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i saw right now that you have to change (roleRegValue == Object.prototype.toString.call(roleRegValue) === '[object Object]') to (Object.prototype.toString.call(roleRegValue) === '[object Object]') to go inside this if

Comment: I didn't really analyze the rest of the program, as I wasn't sure what you were trying to accomplish, but I figured it was enough to get you going.  Glad it helped point you in the right direction. ;)